# How can I define a custom pipeline directive?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

For example something like:

```
pipeline {
   customDirective {
      sh "env"
      ..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible. You can only define custom pipeline steps via a [Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and use them within the stage/steps section and in the condition block of the post section. If you need for any reasons more customization you would have to have a look into the [Scripted pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline).  It allows to use most functionality of Groovy and is therefore very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

**customDirective.groovy (Shared Library)**

```
def call(Closure body) {
     def config = [:]
     body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
     body.delegate = config
     body()
     config.script()
}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
customDirective {
     url="http://something.another.com"
     title="The Title"
     script = {
          sh "env"
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hm, does this really work? I can't find any documentation indicating this can be done in a shared library global function placed in vars/customDirective.groovy. (Which is what I assume you're implying here.)

Comment: yes, it works - in production for over three years